# "He reminds me of me" vs "He reminds me of myself"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Can these two sentences be used interchangeably?

> 1. He reminds me of me.
> 2. He reminds me of myself.

I think the second one is wrong. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can these two sentences be used interchangeably?

Answer: I think not.

Between the two sentences, the second is more appropriate for formal writing. It is also the one that is widely used. See Ngram. The first sentence might sound a bit strange to some people, but it is often used in informal speech.

The first, *"he reminds me of me"*, is more likely to be used in poetry or literary work. It could be used for emphasis, or it could just be a matter of style, habit, or era. This similar post in ELU, [When to use “me” or “myself”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20151/when-to-use-me-or-myself), has some interesting details. Also take a look at this [usage note](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/myself) (when *myself* is used in place of *I/me*) in Dictionary.com.

If it is indeed used for emphasis, or if it is used stylistically, then the author has a specific reason to use it (i.e., the first version *"he reminds me of me"*). The use of "me" instead of "myself" serves a definite purpose. And therefore, in such circumstances, the two sentences are not interchangeable. The author prefers the first version; he is not indifferent between the two.

But an inexperienced user of English language (a new learner) may erroneously use them interchangeably (without having any specific reason for their choice).

This is strange: if you just search google news for *"reminds me of me"*, you will find many celebrities (actors, musicians, and athletes) use this version in their interviews. I suppose the reason for this is that (1) *"reminds me of ME!"* is more emphatic than the version with a dull "myself" or (2) they do so unknowingly (they don't know *myself* is more appropriate for a simple conversation).

> I think the second one is wrong. Am I right?

Answer: You are not. The second sentence, *"He reminds me of myself"*,  is accurate.

Here are some definitions from Wikipedia:

- I      - subjective pronoun - *a personal pronoun that is used as the subject of a verb*
- Me     -  objective pronoun - *a personal pronoun that is used typically as a grammatical object: the direct or indirect object of a verb, or the object of a preposition*
- Myself - reflexive pronoun - *a reflexive pronoun will end in ‑self or ‑selves, and refer to a previously named noun or pronoun* They can act as either objects or indirect objects (Grammarly).

Cambridge discusses reflexive pronouns [here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/pronouns-reflexive-myself-themselves-etc). It says *"we often use reflexive pronouns when the subject and the object of the verb refer to the same person or thing."*

Collins says *"Myself is used as the object of a verb or preposition when the subject refers to the same person."*

> The 'rule' is by no means without exception: *John had his new dressing gown wrapped around him.* - Edwin Ashworth in [ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/343627/reflexive-pronoun-use-when-subject-is-a-subset-of-the-prepositional-object).

"Myself" is also used as an emphatic/intensive pronoun (e.g., I did the entire assignment *myself*, I swear.)

In your second sentence, "me" is the direct object pronoun of the verb "reminds" and "myself" is the object of the preposition "of".

This raises the question then, "What is the relationship between "me" and "myself" in the second sentence?"

The answer to this is in Alex_ander's answer, *"Use 'myself' after a preposition... when the object of the preposition and the object pronoun are the same person."* This quoted material is here: [English Grammar: I, Me, Myself, and My.](http://www.englishteachermelanie.com/english-grammar-i-me-myself-and-my/) Please note that I can't verify the legitimacy of "Melanie"; I searched all her social media sites but I can't find a last name to look up her background (work experience, education, etc.)

What I understand is, "me" is the direct object here, and "myself" is the indirect object.

The second sentence is correct. Google Ngram below shows the usage between the two; it seems that the uses of "me of me" and "reminds me of me" are quite a bit lower than their counterparts with "myself".

[image]
[image]

Comment: If "He reminds me of myself", the other persons would have to work as well. And they do not: Those kids remind me of us, not ourselves.

Comment: No credible source says that the other pronouns would have to work in the same way that "me" and "myself" work. But may sources say that "myself" is often used or should be used when we have a "me" and when they are the same person or thing. Of course it would be "us" and not "ourselves" but I don't understand why you are citing that example, especially because "me" and "us" are not taking about the same person/thing.

Comment: Logic says it:if you can say: "x reminds me of myself", then you can say: "X reminds us of ourselves". Grammar works in patterns. Generating examples is one way of understanding them.

Comment: @Lambie Yes I agree with that - (me + myself) and (us + ourselves). And I agree that - (kids + me + us and not ourselves). That is because its "kids"/"they". And also because I am saying "kids" remind "me" of (me and you = us) - here "me" and "us" are not the same person. I am not making an argument for any general pattern for all reflexives; I am saying when its "me" it should be (me + myself) and not (me + me), exceptions are there as I have mentioned in my post.

Comment: @Lambie, OP does not inquire about a general pattern including other reflexives. And that Is why I have not talked about them in my answer. I just focused on "me" and "myself". Had I said "all reflexives follow this (me+myself) pattern" then I would fully agree with you that the pattern does not hold. But I have only addressed the "me" pronoun, and I believe, I have done so with sufficient justification by citing examples from authoritative sources.

Answer (score 1):

The *Cambridge Dictionary* provides a very helpful explanation of why "myself" is considered correct.

> ### Reflexive pronouns for same subject and object
>
> We often use reflexive pronouns when the subject and the object of the verb refer to the same person or thing:
>
> - He cut **himself** on the broken glass.
> - She made **herself** a cup of tea and sat down in front of the television.
> - Parents often blame **themselves** for the way their children behave.
>
> We use a reflexive pronoun to make it clear who or what is being referred to.
>
> --- [*Cambridge Dictionary*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/pronouns-reflexive-myself-themselves-etc) | [Archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20170828063741/http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/pronouns/pronouns-reflexive-myself-themselves-etc)

In your examples:

> - Maybe: 1. He reminds me of me.
> - ✔️ **Yes:**  2. He reminds me of **myself**.

**Myself** is correct.

However, you may hear someone use "*He reminds me of me*" -- perhaps in movie dialogue -- because it sounds playful, unusual, colloquial (informal), and slightly incorrect on purpose.

Comment: There has to be consistency. Would you ever say: They remind me of ourselves? It would clearly be: They remind me of us. Therefore, of myself is the non-standard one.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Why say "*They remind me of ourselves*" instead of "**They remind *us* of ourselves.**"  That seems like a perfectly good sentence.  See "National Geographic", 2016, ["*Why Do Octopuses Remind Us So Much of Ourselves?*"](https://www.nationalgeographic.com/magazine/2016/11/octopus-anatomy-cephalopod-disguise-evolution/) and R.J. Young (Univ. of Salford), *Wild Equus* (blog), 2015, ["No Wonder We Are So Fascinated by Chimps -- They Remind Us Of Ourselves"](https://wildequus.org/2015/08/28/no-wonder-we-are-so-fascinated-by-chimps-they-remind-us-of-ourselves/)

Comment: I am trying to show that if you want to say, **That or They remind me of us**, you would never say: **They remind me of ourselves**. In other words, the possessive is not standard at  all. If it were, it would work in all persons (I,  you, etc.) and it doesn't.

Comment: The subject is 'He' and the object is 'me' - so not the same person so the rule you have quoted does not apply and does not permit use of 'myself' here.  Other than that I think this is a good answer ...

Answer (score 0):

Most manuals only provide the general rule: 'Use *myself* to direct the action expressed by the verb back to the *subject*' (e.g. '***I*** gave **myself** a bunch of flowers for my birthday.'). 
But here's an additional rule for your example:

> Use *myself* after a preposition... when the object of the preposition and
>   the object pronoun are the same person.
>
> *He asked **me** some questions about **myself**.*
>   http://www.englishteachermelanie.com/english-grammar-i-me-myself-and-my/

Comment: Thanks. Do you think the sentences I gave are interchangeable? Also, I don't trust Melanie a lot. I saw that she'd given some wrong information on some other topics before.

Comment: I would prefer the "myself" form, but I'd rather rephrase to avoid the problem: "He's a lot like me, in some ways"

Comment: I've added a different and perhaps more authoritative citation. Added as an answer.

Comment: "He asked **me** some questions **about myself** is not: He reminds me of my brother; He reminds me of **him**. The possessive does not work with remind.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. The first is standard and the second is colloquial. Here's why:

**to remind someone of someone or something**

The relevant entry from Merriam Webster is [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/remind%20(someone)%20of) :

> Definition of remind (someone) of
>
> 2: to cause (someone) to think of (a similar person or thing)    He
>   reminds me of my uncle.    This painting reminds me of a picture I saw
>   at the Metropolitan Museum.

So, we construct the following sentences:

> - That boy reminds me **of my brother.**
> - That boy reminds me **of him.**

him=my brother

> - These songs remind me **of my family members.**
> - These songs remind me **of them.**    them=family members

- This song reminds me **of my sister.**
- This song reminds me **of her.**
  her=my sister

> - This song reminds **me of your face**.
> - This song reminds me of you.    your face= you
> - This song reminds me of **our love for each other.**
> - This song reminds me of **us.**
> - This song reminds me **of the movie.**
> - This song reminds me **of it.**

The pronouns would be: you, him, her, us, them, it. **Therefore, in the first person, the pronoun has to be *me*, in keeping with the pattern given above** (the object pronouns). In some cases, one can also use the independent possessive pronouns:

> **This reminds me of theirs.** [their clothes]. mine, yours, ours, theirs.

Forgive me for not posting every example again.

> Think about it this way: **in the examples above you would not use the
>   reflexive pronouns. For example:**
>
> - That boy reminds me of himself. [mistake buzzer] OR
> - These songs remind me of ourselves. [mistake buzzer]

- ***That song reminds me of me*.** **That is the grammatically correct form.**

**Saying "That reminds me of myself." is colloquial** as one can clearly see that in no other person (you, he, she, it, we, they) can the reflexive be used in the sample sentence. And that is immediately apparent. And it's funny that in no other person would people even "dream of" using the reflexive pronouns. It's just so obviously not grammatical in those cases.

This explanation is specifically for: remind someone of someone.

Comment: "the pronoun has to be me, *in keeping with the pattern given above*".  This logic doesn't follow.  Because the *reflexive* comes into play precisely in reflexive circumstances, and not at other times. Thus, it breaks the pattern, so to speak.  Of course it would not apply to completely other people like  "him" or "her" or "them".   Consider this definition in dictionary.com  "(used reflexively in place of me as the object of a preposition or as the direct or indirect object of a verb): She asked me for a picture of myself".

Comment: @Sam If you can say: X reminds me of **myself**, the pattern would have to hold. And it doesn't  hold, does it? A picture of myself is not the pattern.  A picture of myself is fine. These songs remind me of us, not ourselves. There the pattern would have to hold. us works, ourselves does not.

Comment: The problem with this "These songs remind me of us" example is that "me" and "we" are not identical.  A reflexive only appears when the subject/object/direct-object are the *same*.  "Me" and "us" are not the same.  However, it can be made to work:  "The couple strolling on the beach, reminded us of ourselves many years earlier."

Answer (score 0):

For me, if I'm having a casual or direct conversations, I would say "She reminds me of Me", it's just a style for improper discussion to emphasize my appearance. But if I'm writing a formal letter or delivering speech, I think it's more appropriate and grammatically right to say "She reminds me of myself".